Create new row index and calculate sum for each column
I have a dataframe that is shaped like this:
        com1     com2     com3
party1   10      0         0
party2   0       20       10 
party3   0       0        25

I want to create a new row index called total, and then take the sum of each column and display it like this
          com1     com2     com3
  party1   10      0         0
  party2   0       20       10 
  party3   0       0        25
Total     10       20       35

I am trying to use an apply function, but I am getting an error becuase 'Total' does not exist
df_pivot = df_pivot.apply(lambda col: df_pivot.loc['Total', col].sum())


Try:
df.loc["Total"] = df.sum()
print(df)

Prints:
        com1  com2  com3
party1    10     0     0
party2     0    20    10
party3     0     0    25
Total     10    20    35

